# Why isn't my WordPress template recognizing my JQuery libraries and CSS files?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I created the following scripts and added them the functions.php file within my WordPress them:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts_styles');
function scripts_styles(){
     if(is_page_template('Disclosures.php')){
       wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.validate.js', array(), GOVPRESS_VERSION, false );
       wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.min.js', array(), GOVPRESS_VERSION, false );
       wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), GOVPRESS_VERSION, false );
       wp_enqueue_script('handlebars',  get_template_directory_uri().'/js/handlebars.min.js', array(), GOVPRESS_VERSION, false );
       wp_enqueue_script('addrows', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/addrows.js', array(), GOVPRESS_VERSION, false );
   }
}

function wpse_enqueue_page_template_styles() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'Disclosures.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrapthemecss', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css', array(), GOVPRESS_VERSION, false );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrapcss', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), GOVPRESS_VERSION, false );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'maincss', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css', array(), GOVPRESS_VERSION, false );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_enqueue_page_template_styles' );
```

However, they are not recognized by my custom template.

In other words, I tested my page with these scripts and stylesheets and they work very well.

I was able to validate form fields and display the results in the styles that was specified.

Yet, they are not validating the same form fields and page is not being styled.

What am I missing?

Just an FYI, the name of the theme is govpress.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. You seem to be enqueuing two scripts with the same name: `jquery`.  However, `jquery` is already present in WordPress and you might notice [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) description says: ***does NOT override***. This means whenever you are trying to enqueue a script with the same name as a previously enqueued script... nothing happens.
2. If you're not happy with the existing version of `jquery` embedded in WP, you need to deregister it and register the new one, with this exact name: `jquery`. The name is very important, as a lot of WP scripts depend on `jquery`. If you replace it, they'll depend on your version instead of the included one. Make sure you enqueue a version of `jquery` regardless of your templates logic (if you removed the default one).
3. You should specify `jquery` as a dependency in the dependencies array of each script that depends on `jquery`.
4. If none of your scripts and styles load, you might want to debug your script checking if `is_page_template('Disclosures.php')` returns true in the page you're testing this on. A simple `die('this just happened...')` will do for testing purposes.

Comment: First of all, thank you for pointing this important fact about jquery and wordpress.

Second, I commented the jquery out from the scripts I posted here. Tested again, same issue.

Then I used the debuggrer, If is_page_template('Disclosures.php') then die(...), again, nothing happened to the page.

Comment: This means the page you're testing on doesn't use the `Disclosures.php` template and that's why none of your resources load. Because the condition is not true.

Comment: What do you mean by page I am testing on does not use Disclosure template?

I am testing form fields that inside the Disclosures.php template. Maybe, there is a teachable moment here because I had always believed that once you put the comment at top naming the template you are working with, and you have the if is_page() conditional, it will recognize the template. Am I missing something?

Comment: I mean you should carefully read docs on each function you use. Note  [`is_page_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/)  does not check the name you have provided in the top comment of the file, but the file name. Feel free to use any other WP conditional function you might see fit for your purpose.

Comment: I completely agree with you Andrei that it cares more about the filename than the name at top and the name of the file I am using is Disclosures.php.

Exactly same name and same casing. That's why I am baffled.

Another question I have is that if you look at those scripts I posted, you see something like ` array(), GOVPRESS_VERSION, false );~, the way I understand it is that we basically, this script is from GovPress but our own custom script. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: Is it a proper page template, that you have selected from page templates box, in the edit screen section of your page? Is it the selected (and saved) page template for your page?

Comment: Yes, I actually published it because I am using our sandbox before we push to production.

So, each time a change is made, it is save and republished. Also, I add more comments to my previous post. Can you please give your thoughts on that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136913/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-kenny).